# Hangfire on ASP.Net MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I installed hangfire 1.6.3 and followed the steps in quick start guide.
Added owin class with

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangFire");

            app.UseHangfireDashboard();
            app.UseHangfireServer();
        }
```

But when i navigate to /hangfire it gives a 404 error. I tried creating a job

```
 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Daily Job"), Cron.Minutely);
```

but this does not work too. I checked output window nothing comes there, nothing happens even when i set breakpoint on any of those lines.

What am i missing

Comment: 1. Do you have a connection string named "Hangfire"?          2. Could you just try with manager class -> var manager = new RecurringJobManager();
manager.AddOrUpdate("some-id", Job.FromExpression(() => YourMethod()), Cron.Minutely);

Comment: @Developer this is my con string   <add name="HangFire" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Database=BHHangFire;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  
and it did not work with the code you provided

Comment: @Developer also none of the tables have been created, even though database exists

Comment: Is this method being executed without errors?

Comment: @Developer Never mind got the issue the owin class was not executing. Thanks for your time anyway

Comment: No probs, had a hunch that this Owin class is not being called, thats why I asked whether this method being executed. I have faced this same issue before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case all i had to do

```
  <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

was change the false to true in web.config. I dont know why was it set as false